# What is yt, ytd, ytd-app kind of html tags in youtube?

Tags: youtube

[image]
when inspecting on youtube website we can see tags like

ytd-app, yt-activity-manager, yt-guide-manager, yt-gfeedback-manager, yt-mdx-manager
ytd-thumbnail, ytd-rich-item-renderer, ytd-rich-grid-renderer,
ytd-channel-legal-info-renderer

how to create this tags? is it custom made tags ?

Comment: See https://react-etc.net/entry/youtube-is-being-rebuilt-on-web-components-and-polymer -and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

Answer (score 1):

They are html Web Components `customElements`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

Answer (score 0):

It is not a new thing, we can create custom HTML tags and elements, and all the created elements will have some default properties given by the browser.

like all these kinds of elements will be "**Inline**" by default.

```html
 <p> for example : </p>
 
  <aniket> Hello World </aniket> 

 <!-- This is valid but not a good practice -->
```

Hope this is helpful !